# objective-c, object_getClassName(obj) vs NSStringFromClass([obj class])

Tags: objective-c

i ran into a bug, and find the reason is object_getClassName(app) not return "UIApplication".
can anyone explain the difference between these two methods?

code:

```
id app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

// 1
object_getClassName(app); //output:NSKVONotifying_UIApplication

// 2
NSStringFromClass([app class]); //output:UIApplication
```

Comment: Can you try `class_getName([app class])` ? Also, what are you trying to do with the class name?

Comment: @jtbandes, class_getName([app class]) return "UIApplication";I have lua binding by tolua++, when push objective-c object to lua ,i need the class name to get the right metatable

Answer (score 0):

`object_getClassName` is returning the raw class name;  this is the true class of the object.

`[app class]` or `NSStringFromClass()` (not sure which) is returning the "developer friendly" class that is in play.

`NSKVONotifying_UIApplication` is an at-runtime dynamically created class to support KVO.